# angularjs/gettext: how to translate text in attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gettext, angular-gettext

I have a piece of html like this

```
<bar title="'My Title'"></bar>
```

Now, when I want to translate it, it looks like this

```
<bar title="'My Title'|translate"></bar>
```

The reason why I dont have {{ and }} is because the 'bar' directive binds the title to its scope with '='

```
scope: {
    title: '=',
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the task 'nggettext_extract' doesn't extract this text, because it is looking for things in between curly brackets. I found a hack to solve this problem:

```
<bar dummy="{{My Title'|translate}}" title="'My Title'|translate"></bar>
```

But I hope there is a better solution to this problem ?

UPDATE: The workaround I've implemented now is that I changed the directive as follows

```
scope: true,
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.title = attrs.title;
}
```

Of course, if someone knows a better solution please let me know!

Comment: translate inside the `bar` directive?

Comment: nope, that doesn't work, the process is not smart enough to resolve variables.

Comment: Inside `bar` directive: `$filter('translate')(title)`. Note that is necessary to inject the filter dependency

Comment: this doesn't work in the extract phase (nggettext_extract)

Comment: does this approach triggers also dynamic language changes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you explain in more detail what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
// Inside your controller

$scope.lbl = gettextCatalog.getString('Some text');

// And inside your template you can use

<bar title={{lbl}} > </bar>
```